# String replace in python using if statement

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to replace a string based on column value, getting the error 
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
if df['Target'] == 'U':
   df['Target'] = df['Action']
```

Getting the Error
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Just I need to check the string and replace it with another column value if matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.where`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

df['Target'] = np.where(df['Target'] == "U", df['Action'], df['Target'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df["Target"] == 'U', "Target"] = df["Action"]
```

You can also use [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where)

```
df["Target"].where(df["Target"] != 'U', df["Action"], inplace = True)
```

Note that in this case the cells that does **NOT** satisfy the condition are replaced, that's why you have to use `!=` instead of `==`.